# passing extras with intent to doBind()

Tags: android

I'd like to pass to Servive with intent extras:

```
ArrayList<String> playlistStr;
int current;
```

It looks now this way:

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_top);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("playlist")) {
        playlistStr = (ArrayList<String>) (getIntent().getExtras().get("playlist"));
        playlist = new Playlist(playlistStr);
    }
    if (!playlist.isEmpty()) {

        playlistView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playlistView.setVisibleItems(5);
        playlistView.setViewAdapter(new PlaylistViewAdapter(this));

        try {
            updatePlaylist(playlistView, playlist, playlistView.getCurrentItem());

            if (mBound){
                unbindService(mConnection);
                mBound = false;
            }

//BINDING SERVICE

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerManager.class);
            intent.putExtra("playlistStr",playlistStr);
            intent.putExtra("current",current);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        playlistView.addClickingListener(new OnWheelClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(WheelView wheel, int itemIndex) {
                prev = playlistView.getCurrentItem();
                playlistView.setCurrentItem(itemIndex);
                playlistView.scroll(itemIndex - playlistView.getCurrentItem(), 0);
                current = playlistView.getCurrentItem();

                try {
                    mService.start(current);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

MediaPlayerManager.class

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onBind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (intent.hasExtra("playlistStr")) {
        playlistStr = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getExtras().get("playlistStr");
        playlist = new Playlist(playlistStr);
        if (!playlist.isEmpty())
            song = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(playlist.get(0)));
    }
    if (intent.hasExtra("current"))
        current = intent.getIntExtra("current",-1);

    return mBinder;
}
```

in MainActivity.class both playlistStr and current has right value (playlistStr is not empty and current > 0). However in Service playlistStr = [] and current = 0. Where can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain you need the `playlist` object as you may just use the strings listed in `playlistStr`
Also you might want to explicitly use `Intent.getSerializableExtra`

```
    playlistStr = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("playlistStr");
    //playlist = new Playlist(playlistStr);
    if (!playlistStr.isEmpty())
        song = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(playlistStr.get(0)));
```

Comment: Thanks foryour interest! I need Playlist somewhere else. Anyway it doesn't matter cause playlistStr is empty already even if it shouldn't be. I will check your solution with 'serializable' extra, however there is still the question remaining why my version doesn't work (i pass ArrayList <String> somewhere else in code exactly in that way and everything works fine).

Comment: Nope. As I thought: using getExtras(), getSerializableExtra() and getStringArrayListExtra() - none of these things work.